# IDL procedure won't compile

Tags: compilation, idl

I've made an IDL procedure which is very simple and I'd like to use in my other codes. I've put the path in my directory and I can't see a name conflict anywhere.

When I try to run the procedure from another it tells me

```
!PATH=!PATH+':'+Expand_Path('+~/example/')
```

But when I try to find the procedure using "Findpro" I get

```
Procedure CHLOADCT found in directory  /data/clh93/colortables/CH/
```

So my paths are right. I don't understand why it won't find my procedure, does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks!
Christina

Answer (score 0):

Things to check in situations like this:

1. you are consistent about whether the routine is a function or procedure, i.e., routine is procedure and you are calling it as a procedure
2. routine you are calling is either compiled already or the last routine in a file named the same as it with a `.pro` extension; the case of the filename and routine call must match or the filename must be all lowercase (just use all lowercase in filenames!)
3. quick check to see if `my_routine.pro` is in your `!path`:

   ```
   IDL> print, file_which('my_routine.pro')
   ```

   It will return an empty string if it can't find it.
4. make sure the file is not in your `!path` twice and you are getting someone else's or an old version